# Calling a one way WCF service from Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, web-services, asynchronous

Just been reading this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/09/20/using-wcf-on-windows-phone-7-walk-through.aspx

The article states: "WCF from Silverlight is all asynchronous"

How do you call a WCF service that has a void return? Do you just call it asynchrononsly, but have no call back method defined?

Comment: I guess so, but the callback can be used for handling exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The callback still makes sense from the client side perspective. There's no waiting for a *logical* result in this case, but you still issued an asynchronous network request and therefore there is still a question of whether or not that succeeded. So the callback would basically be for notifying you that the message was sent successfully or if there was an communication issue of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

With a void return type WCF wouldn't create an event args subclass for that particular service method and you wouldn't get a "Result" from the service.

Rather than using AddCompletedEventArgs, you would use the base class AsyncCompletedEventArgs and just make sure that no exception was thrown and passed to your client:

```
client.AddCompleted += new EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(client_AddCompleted);

...

void client_AddCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Notice there is no e.Result

    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // Do something with the error
    }
}
```